# How to handle async promise rejections inside an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async function that looks like this:

```js
async function foo() {
  const promises = [];

  for await (const value of asyncIterable) {
    promises.push( doSomething(value) ); // `doSomething` returns a promise.
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

The goal is to `doSomething` with each `value`, but there's a problem: *if a promise returned by `doSomething()` rejects before the iterator is over, that rejection is not handled*, because the `async function` hasn't reached `await Promise.all(promises);`. My goal is to make it so **when any of the `promises` reject, the promise returned by the `async function` rejects** (like it would with a sync iterator). (If the promise returned by `doSomething()` rejects *after* the iterator is over, the rejection wiould be catched by `Promise.all()`, which would make the promise returned by `Promise.all()` reject, and since that promise is being `await`ed by the async function, it will throw.)

The only (good) solution I can think of is this:

```js
/**
 * @param {Promise} p
 * @param {Promise[]} array
 * @returns {Promise} A promise that resolves with the value of `p` when it resolves
 * or rejects when any of the promises reject with the respective value
 */
function join(p, array) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        p.then(res, rej);
        for (const promise of array)
            promise.catch(rej);
    });
}

async function foo() {
  const promises = [];

  const asyncIterator = asyncIterable[Symbol.asyncIterator]
  let value, done;
  while (true) {
    ({ value, done } = await join(asyncIterator.next(), promises));
    if (done)
      break;
    promises.push( doSomething(value) ); // `doSomething` returns a promise.
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

As you can see, it's not very elegant. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Could you just `await doSomething()` inside the loop?

Comment: "*make it so when any of the promises reject*" - do you mean "**if** any of the promises reject", or do you mean "**as soon as**"?

Comment: @Bergi The goal of using `Promise.all()` is to `doSomething` concurrently, and `await`ing inside the loop makes the calls synchronous. I mean "as soon as", like the promise returned by `Promise.all()` rejects *as soon as* any of the promises passed to it reject.

Comment: I see. Given that you also want to abort the loop as soon as any of the promises reject, yeah there's no better way than the custom async iteration you wrote. All you can do is extract this into a helper function to which you pass the iterable and the callback function.